# SSH connection is not working @ showing "colab@0.tcp.in.ngrok.io: Permission denied (publickey,password)."

Tags: ssh, carla, google-colaboratory

procedure followed:

1. run the colab  code
2. after generating the root, **colab password** , vnc password..etc and **ssh command**
3. cmd=> ssh command copied from result of colab

[image: ssh rejection after pasting the colab password].

**link to colab code from GitHub:**

https://colab.research.google.com/github/MichaelBosello/carla-colab/blob/master/carla-simulator.ipynb#scrollTo=w4Ywwr43AGR9

followed the below site for  resolving(not worked):

1. https://github.com/demotomohiro/remocolab/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-get-ssh-client-on-windows
2. https://internet-of-tomohiro.netlify.app/google_colab/ssh.en.html

Thank you in advance
@new to ssh concept

Answer (score 0):

By using public key authentication, you can login to ssh server without copy&pasting a password.
For example, you can generate your key with following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521
```

Then specify content of your public key to public_key argument of remocolab.setupSSHD() like remocolab.setupSSHD(public_key = "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAA...").

See README.md of remocolab for more details:
https://github.com/demotomohiro/remocolab/blob/master/README.md